# Ruby pipe operator on nil and array

Tags: ruby

So I have been using | to merge two arrays and get unique values.

but I found out that `nil | ["foo", "bar"]` returns `true` instead of `["foo", "bar"]`.

Can someone explain this behaviour? Ruby version is 2.2.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil` is the receiver in your example, and [`NilClass#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/NilClass.html#method-i-7C) coerces the right-hand side of the expression (the argument) to a boolean value. The expression is the equivalent of `nil | !!(["foo", "bar"])`, and because `nil` is always falsey and arrays are never falsey, it reduces to `false | true`, which will always return true. The same is true for other non-falsey values on the right-hand side:

```
irb(main):001:0> nil|0
=> true
irb(main):002:0> nil|1
=> true
irb(main):003:0> nil|"foo"
=> true
irb(main):004:0> nil|true
=> true
irb(main):005:0> nil|false
=> false
irb(main):006:0> nil|nil
=> false
```

You can keep doing what you're doing, but if the receiver might be `nil` (or really anything other than an array), you should coerce it into an array to get the [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) behavior you desire. Fortunately, there's a really neat and easy way to do that in Ruby:

```
[*nil] | ["foo", "bar"]
```

This "does the right thing" in a variety of cases:

```
irb(main):001:0> [*nil] | ["foo", "bar"]
=> ["foo", "bar"]
irb(main):002:0> var = "foo"
=> "foo"
irb(main):003:0> [*var] | ["foo", "bar"]
=> ["foo", "bar"]
irb(main):004:0> var = ["bar"]
=> ["bar"]
irb(main):005:0> [*var] | ["foo", "bar"]
=> ["bar", "foo"]
irb(main):006:0> var = []
=> []
irb(main):007:0> [*var] | ["foo", "bar"]
=> ["foo", "bar"]
irb(main):008:0> var = nil
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> [*var] | ["foo", "bar"]
=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: that's a really quick and detailed answer, thanks! Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

| is actually bitwise or in ruby.It means integers are treated as sequence of bytes instead of whole numbers.It takes the logical inclusion OR operation of corresponding bits

```
1|0  => 1
1|1 => 1
1|2 => 3
```

incase of boolean operator it is similar to ||

```
true|false => true
false|false => false
nil|false => false
```

false|obj => true or false
nil|obj => true or false
. it turns out nilclass is overridden

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/NilClass.html#method-i-7C

in case of array it is neither bitwise or or logical or but array union .please find the documentation.
http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html